# Minimum number of points to specify a sine wave

Tags: math, signal-processing

I am generating a sine wave from a DAC at a constant frequency. If each full cycle is specified by N data points what is the relationship between the accuracy of the rendered sine wave and N?

N=1 will obviously be pulses. N=4 (peaks and zero crossings) will yield a triangular wave of sorts. Is there some equation that shows how good a sine wave approximation is being created? [Obviously I can put it through a post DAC filter to smooth it etc]

Comment: You might be better off [asking on dsp](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just cross posted to the DSP group - thanks

Comment: Please don't cross-post - it causes all sorts of problems - either flag a moderator to migrate this question, or just delete it and start again on DSP.SE. Probably too late now to migrate this question - I'll re-post my answer on DSP.SE so that you can delete the question here.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/13128/29

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a formula, but I do know from experimentation that N=256 gives a sine wave with a reasonable SNR for general audio use, although if you want full 16 bit accuracy (i.e. > 90 dB SNR) you'll probably need to go higher than this.

If you're stepping through the sine wave LUT at a non-integer rate (to generate an arbitrary frequency) then using interpolation between LUT values reduces SNR such that you can use a smaller LUT than if you don't interpolate (e.g. if you just truncate the sample index).

Comment: A bit more info. I am interested in this as part of a range finding experiment using ultrasonics. I want to compare the entirety of the reflected wave with the transmitted one, not just a single peak to peak one off measurement

Comment: Ideally you need to specify your required SNR - it would also be useful to know the resolution of the ADCs and DACs that you are using.

Comment: Not sure what the required SNR, but we have 12 bits of ADC/DAC

Comment: BTW, LUT table size is not limited and so interpolation is not a factor

Comment: In the most general case what I am trying to do is convert 12 bits of amplitude information into 12 bits of timing resolution

Comment: Well if table size is not constrained then just go for, say, a 4096 point table - that should have more than enough resolution to keep your SNR within the range of 12 bit quantization noise.

Comment: True, but I cannot read them out fast enough to do an arbitrary precision sine wave at the frequencies of interest. I can only use between 12 and 96 samples depending on which embedded processor and DAC I choose. The more samples, the more expensive it will be in production.

Comment: OK - you said "LUT table size is not limited" above, but it sounds like in practice it is. Do you have a fixed sample rate (or a choice of fixed sample rates) ?

Comment: I will be running at the max sample rate I can go eg 5 Msps for a waveform of around 200kHz

Comment: OK - so you have 25 samples for your LUT - do you have a decent reconstruction filter after your DAC ? Or can you tolerate a certain amount of distortion ?

Comment: I need to somehow quantify the distortion. I think that in practice perhaps I should ignore the precision of the transmitted wave and just compare multiple reflections against each other. These can be almost guaranteed to have the same distortion (or lack of it).

Comment: How about if you just do the comparison at the fundamental frequency and ignore any harmonic content from the distortion ? Or might there be non-linearities in the system you are working with ?

Comment: I think a lot of this will be determined experimentally, so setting up test gear even as I write...

Comment: OK - sounds like fun - good luck with the project and come back with more questions as they arise.